# How to debug a Windows service which stops immediately after it starts

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I currently found an issue that one of my projects, which is a windows service, stops immediately after it starts. It was not like this before.

Worse still, I am unable to attach the service to Visual Studio since it stopped immediately after it started.

My system is Windows server 2012 R2 and Visual Studio is 2013.

Is there any way for me to debug the service?

Comment: Does the EventLog (Application, Security) give any clues?

Comment: Yes, but the error message doesn't make too much sense. It just says: SimpleInjector.ActivationException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found an answer in MSDN.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cktt23yw.aspx

Add the following code:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

At the very beginning of OnStart method. Then run net start serviceName (administrative credential is needed)

Answer (score 0):

You can start the service directly under debugger. To achieve this you can either modify the service start command ([`sc config binPath=`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) or you can use [GFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549566(v=vs.85).aspx) to alter the service image to start under debugger. In both cases your debugger will be in the background and you'll need to then remote into it.

But usually you can solve the issue from dumps, if any. Often simply starting the service executable from the same account as the service will reveal the issue.

Finaly lets not forget the power of `printf`. Add logging and isolate the issue from the logs. Your service should be doing this *anyway*.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to use the sc config binPath to the binary file under the visual studio build folder and then start debugging in Visual Studio ?